# Problema with angular template

Tags: angular, frontend

I've created a new application using command line (ng new) and it gave me default files.
Then I created a login component using ng g c login, and in the routing file I'm using redirect like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

When I go to localhost:4200 in the browser, the url changes to localhost:4200 as expected, but keeps using the default app.component.html instead of showing the login.component.html, with is in the LoginComponent file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there a `<router-outlet>` in the app.component.html ? Is there any error in the browser's console ?

Comment: There is no error in the console. But I do not have this router-outlet. I'm going to search how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you must add
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the parent component
that represents the placeholder of the place you want to render the components in.
this is the place where components will change according to the route